# Grant temporary access to Ubuntu 14.04 EC2 machines

Tags: ssh, security, amazon-ec2

My company intends to hire an external contractor for some dev-ops jobs on our EC2 servers. We use Ubuntu accessed using a `.pem` certificate file.

For obvious reasons, I do not want to share my `.pem` key with an outsider - if the key is lost, anyone on the internet can access my machines.

I can add the contractor's ssh key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` on all the servers, but that would be tedious and new servers won't be accessible by him unless I change the template server image.

**Is there an easier way to grant temporary, revokable access to EC2 machines?**

Comment: You say you use keys to access your servers, but it's not clear in your question whether the public keys are setup in a per-user basis(i.e. everyone with access to the server has an account) or you access the same accounts on the servers.

Comment: If adding an SSH authorized key is tedious, you need a configuration management system like Ansible.

Comment: I am the only employee for now, so I have my `.pem` file on all the machines. For a safety measure, I have also placed my own `id_rsa.pub` file on all of them.

Comment: What I'm asking is if you have your own account or just log as `root` everywhere.

Comment: I use the `ubuntu` account and `sudo`.

Comment: What safety do you think that keeping your public key on your servers affords you?

Comment: @EEAA I will not lose access to all of my machines if my `.pem` file is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If there is a centralized authentication system in place:

Yes, this can be done quite easily, for obvious reasons. Simply enable/disable the contractor's account in your centralized authentication system (LDAP, Kerberos, AD, ...). You can have a personal account for this specific contractor, or decide to use a generic third-party-people account. The former can retain auditability, if that matters.

### If there is not a centralized authentication system in place:

Create a key pair for the contractor and place it in your machines using your configuration management of choice. If you don't have one, you can use `ansible`'s `shell` module, which requires nothing at the client side, or, as a last resort, you can still use `mussh` or script yourself something around `ssh-copy-id(1)`. Remove the key, revoke access in `sshd_config`, or both, once she/he has finished her/his job.

Comment: I'm so glad to see ansible being presented in more and more answers here. I've been using it for the past 4 months or so, and am completely smitten by it. :)

Comment: In this case, the agentless architecture of `ansible` is very convenient.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Do you know any recommended getting-started guide to ansible's shell?

Comment: The project's [online documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_adhoc.html) is quite good.